# echo results from PDO query, returns empty?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm learning PDO so be gentle with me!
I'm trying to echo out my query made with PDO, but the string returns empty.
What am i missing here?

**PHP**

```
$query = "SELECT 1 
          FROM table 
          WHERE c1 = :c1 && c2 = :c2"; 

$query_params = array( ':c1' => $c1, ':c2' => $c2 ); 
try{ 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex){
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$row = $stmt->fetch(); //Now $row should hold values of c1 & c2, right?

//This is What i've tried
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$row."');</script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$row[0]."');</script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$row[1]."');</script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$row['c1']."');</script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$result."');</script>";
```

Comment: `SELECT 1 ` ? or `SELECT * `

Comment: When you SELECT 1, you only get `1` :)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky The purpose is to only select 1 row from db. But do you mean if i use `SELECT 1` it returns number "1"? Not the record from db?

Comment: Exactly it does. To select only one row you use LIMIT 1 at the end

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need one row use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE c1 = :c1 && c2 = :c2 LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

you need this query:

SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE [...your params..]  LIMIT 1